# filtering the products returned by launching google play intent with market:// protocol

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to leverage Google Play for the purchase of saved songs in a music player app I'm working on; so far only searching via HTTPS as follows works:

```
Intent searchInPlay = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
searchInPlay.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?
q="+productQuery+"&c=music"));
startActivity(searchInPlay);
```

This brings up a dialog of choices for the user, including all web browsers and the Google Play app itself.  Selecting a web browser navigates to the Google Play website and the URI given above filters to music based on the input query string (which just consists of song title, artist, etc.)  Selecting the Google Play app leads to a 'No results found for {query}' screen.  I've also tried the market URI protocol as detailed by Google [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#android-app) as follows:

```
Intent searchInPlay = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
searchInPlay.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q="+productQuery+"&c=music"));
startActivity(searchInPlay);
```

but that yields the same 'No results found for {query}' view.  I suspect that the &c=music category filter is not being read properly by the Google Play app, but I'm not sure.

How can I search for products by category in the Google Play app using the market uri protocol?

Comment: Maybe obvious question, but are you URL encoding ``productQuery``?  Also, if you remove ``&c=music`` from the first (https) form, do you get any results?

Comment: I am encoding productQuery as a valid URL, yes, and if I remove &c=music from the https request, I get unfiltered results from the Google Play website.  Usually apps that might be related are listed first, then albums, then tracks from the music category.  Adding the &c=music for the website at least automatically filters to the music category.